# Is there a way I can share data stored in Hazelcast server members(A,B,C) in AKS cluster 1 with Hazelcast Server members (D,E,F) in AKS cluster 2

Tags: azure, kubernetes, hazelcast

I have 3 nodes (members) of Hazelcast server and 3 nodes (members) of Hazelcast client running in Kubernetes cluster of `east region`.
I have 3 nodes (members) of Hazelcast server and 3 nodes (members) of Hazelcast client running in Kubernetes cluster of `west region`.

My use case is to store data in both east and west region kubernetes clusters so that if any of the region is down, we can get data from another.
I am using `Azure Kubernetes` service and namespace name is same in both region clusters.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the use case that the WAN replication feature was designed for; it provides disaster recovery capabilities by replicating the content of a cluster (either completely, or just selected IMaps) to a remote cluster. WAN replication is an Enterprise feature, so it isn't available in the Open Source distribution.

If you're trying to do something similar in Open Source, you could write MapListeners that observe all changes made on one cluster and then send the changes to the remote cluster. The advantage of WAN replication (other than not having to write it yourself) is that it has optimizations to batch writes together, configuration options to help trade off performance vs. consistency, and very efficient delta sync logic to help efficiently resynchronize clusters after a network or other outage.